# Discord bot JS: Delete amount of messages for a specific user ID on a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm new to .JS language and have been programming a discord bot using Discord.js v12.22.4, but I cannot find a way to filter the messages that are being deleted on a channel.

The line `message.channel.bulkDelete(3);` works for deleting all the last three messages, but I need to delete only the bot messages and keep the user's messages on that channel.

I have searched the entire internet trying to find a way around it, including the .js documentation, but no success. All the codes I tried gave me errors because the syntax is outdated. **My question is: How can I delete a specific amount of messages, from a specific user's ID, from a specific discord channel?**

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some of what you tried already (as in, the code you tried out)? It is much easier for answerers to answer your question by correcting potential mistakes in what you tried (or updating the syntax) as opposed to creating an entirely new solution and reinventing the wheel. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; this may be why your question appears to have been downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one website explaining the syntax I was looking for. Hope it helps someone else:

```js
message.channel.messages
  .fetch({ 
    limit: 2 
  })
  .then((messages) => {
    const botMessages = messages.filter((msg) => msg.author.bot)

    message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages)
  })
```